# Cannot connect to the service chromedriver (Mac)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried many solutions that others provided on stackoverflow as well as other sites, nothing seems to be working and I have no idea what to do anymore.. This is what ive basically been doing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# from chromedriver_py import binary_path

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

The error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

I've tried:

1. adjusting my host file in etc/hosts
2. using an os environ variable for the location of the chromedriver
3. using chromedriver_py for the binary path
4. Double checked that chromedriver version is the same as my chrome version

Not sure if this is relevant but im using:

- MacOs Sierra 10.12.6
- PyCharm 2019 CE

Comment: It's probably permissions problem. Do you have execution permission in chromedriver?

Comment: @RubénParedes Yes, I gave it permission to run from the security & privacy settings if thats what you mean

Comment: If you use "ls -l" in terminal, you see the permissions i mean, the output should be something like this "... -rwxr-xr-x@ ...". It's important that you have the first rwx, so you can read, write and execute it as owner.

Comment: @RubénParedes Yup, I have this: -rwxr-xr-x@ 1

Comment: Hmm, so I recommend that you put the executable in the same folder where you have the script and update this: driver = webdriver.Chrome ('./ chromedriver')

Comment: @RubénParedes still shows the same error. I think the path is correct, something else needs to be changed im just not sure what it is..

Comment: Then sorry, I don't know, keep trying.